# Selectively insert rows based on if the row already exists or not

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have a table that has several thousand entries. I've found a way to insert of a new row of data for all entries in the system (see example below), but unfortunately, I just found out that some of the entries have the value already in there. I'm trying to figure out how to selectively run the INSERT INTO function based on if the row already exists or not.

```
Column 1   Column 2   Column 3 
10         Address    True 
10         City       False
10         State      True
20         Address    True
20         City       True
20         State      True
20         NEW        NEW*

Column 1   Column 2   Column 3
10         Address    True
10         City       False
10         State      True
10         NEW        NEW
20         Address    True
20         City       True
20         State      True
20         NEW        NEW
```

The code I've used for the insert is:

```
insert into table-name(Column1, Column2, Column3)
  select 
     Column1, 'NEW', 'NEW*' 
  from 
     table-name 
  group by 
     Column1
```

I'm assuming I need to use an `IF/ELSE` statement, but I'm running into issues on the `IF` statement. Currently, I'm using the following code:

```
IF Column 2 like 'New' leave NULL
ELSE 
  insert into table-name(Column1, Column2, Column3)
     select 
         Column1, 'NEW', 'NEW*' 
     from table-name 
     group by Column1
```

I know the IF statement is wrong, but trying to figure out what to do to leave the existing row values the same if they are already populated.

Comment: Double check the formatting of your question. It's very difficult to parse at the moment.  NM..I see it's fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SQL Server, you can do a NOT EXISTS

```
insert into table-name(Column1, Column2, Column3)
  select 
     Column1, 'NEW', 'NEW*' 
  from 
     table-name 
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table-name xref WHERE xref.Column1 = table-name.Column1 AND xref.Column2 = 'NEW')
  group by 
     Column1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the INSERT IGNORE INTO 
or INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax

see http://bogdan.org.ua/2007/10/18/mysql-insert-if-not-exists-syntax.html
and
dev.mysql.com

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is an "INSERT INTO" with an "ON DUPLICATE KEY".

See:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: I've tried the ON DUPLICATE KEY approach, but I don't believe it works in Microsoft SQL Server. Please correct me if I'm wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server use a CTE to define your dataset to be inserted:

```
WITH NonDupes (<your fieldlist>)
AS
(SELECT <your fieldlist> FROM <your tables> WHERE <tablea>.<column> NOT IN (SELECT <column> FROM <tableb>))
INSERT INTO
<tableb>
VALUES(SELECT * FROM NonDupes)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Merge statement to insert only rows that don't exist.  As an added bonus you can update existing rows in the same statement if you need to do that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx